# Mac + PyCharm + Python 2.7: ImportError: No module named appium

Tags: automated-testing, python, appium, mobile-automation, pytest

I just changed **PyCharm** application from **Professional to community** and in my v first run I am getting below error. Prior this all tests was working correctly as expected:

> ImportError while importing test module '/Users/......./test.py'.
>   Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
>   Traceback: test.py:3: in 
>       from appium import webdriver E   **ImportError: No module named appium**

I can suspect - This **issue must be with some configuration.** But goos to know If anyone had fixed this already.
Thanks in adv!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check whether you have missed something from below migration steps:

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000417800-How-to-switch-from-the-Ultimate-version-to-Community-one

Comment: Thanks. This would be helpful, But I did un-installation and installed new after that observed. 
I have to re-install pip, Appium-Python-Client 0.40, enum 0.4.7, etc again which made my setup working back. Below are the steps:
1. PyCharm Preferences  2. Search : Project Interpreter 3. Click on "+" sign 4. Select pkg to install 5. Click on Install Package